# Show that $\prod\limits_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in F} \pi _\alpha^{-1}(A_\alpha)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How to prove the following

Let $I\neq\emptyset$ and $\{X_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ a family of nonempty sets. For each $\alpha\in I,$ let $A_\alpha\subset X_\alpha$ and let $F=\{\alpha\in I: A_\alpha\neq X_\alpha\}.$ Show that $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha=\bigcap_{\alpha\in F} \pi _\alpha^{-1}(A_\alpha).$

I have no idea how to prove it, could anyone guide me please?

Maybe a hint? or maybe 2 hints?

Note I am not asking for the proof since I know this site doesn't work like that

Comment: What is $\pi_{\alpha}$? You never define it

Comment: A single term of the intersection is A_alpha × the product of all X's except X_alpha.

Comment: F is misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$. This means (by definition) that $f: I \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ and $f(\alpha) \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in I$.

$\pi_\alpha(f) = f(\alpha)$ (by definition), so for each $\alpha$ we have that $\pi_\alpha(f) \in A_\alpha$< or equivalently $f \in \pi_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$, and as this holds for each $\alpha$, so a fortiori for $\alpha \in F$, we have that $f \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in F} \pi_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$. This shows one inclusion.

The reverse direction: let $f \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in F} \pi_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$. Consider $\alpha \in I$: If $\alpha \in F$ we we know that $f \in \pi_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$, so $f(\alpha) = \pi_\alpha(f) \in A_\alpha$; if $\alpha \notin F$ ,$A_\alpha = X_\alpha$ by definition of $F$, so it's trivial in that case (as $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$) that indeed $f(\alpha) \in X_\alpha = A_\alpha$ also in that case. So $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$.

If you unpack the definitions it's basically a tautology.

Comment: Just one little detail in the original exercise it was F here $\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} \pi_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$ instead of $I$, but It doesn't really matter right? The proof is the same right?

Comment: William Elliot modified the title of my question and changed F by I

Comment: why $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ ?

Comment: Because both sides are subsets of it. It’s the total space, and we’re proving equality of two of its subsets.@Isabella

Comment: $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ is the total space?

Comment: @Isabella Yes, of course it is.

Comment: @Isabella $\pi_\alpha$ is defined as a map from the product $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ to $X_\alpha$.

Comment: ok I didn't know it now I see it's trivial as you said before :) many thanks

Comment: I was reading the proof again and I think in the domain of $f$ should be $I$ instead of $A$ here: $f: A \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ and $f(\alpha) \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in I$ or maybe to change $A$ instead of $I$ here: $\alpha \in I$. But if the last were the case, I don't see where does $A$ came from.

Comment: @Isabella indeed a typo. Usually I use $\alpha\in A$ or $i \in I$ as index sets and elements of it. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Actually I did not refer to that part of the proof, I would refer to the first part where you say how $f$ is defined $f: A \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$. It should be $I$ instead of $A$?

Comment: @Isabella yes, that’s the same confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cap_{j\in I} \ pi_j^{-1}(A_\alpha)  
= \cap_{j\in I} \{ A_j × \prod_{k\in I-\{j\}} X_k \}  
= \prod_{j\in I} A_j $$